# Problems getting excel to run vba code when a cell is selected

Tags: vba, excel, range, target

I have written the function below, but I get an error that this is unable to compile due to a time mismatch on the If intersect... line. Debugging shows the value of the selected cell when I hover over 'Target' rather than the range (I don't know if this is indicative of the problem)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim lastEntry As Integer
Dim shiftEntries As Range

lastEntry = LastEntryRow()
Set shiftEntries = Range("A11:L" & lastEntry)

If Intersect(Target, shiftEntries) Then
    Dim shiftDate As String
    shiftDate = Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value
    Cells(10, 15) = ShiftsInSevenDays(shiftDate)
End If
End Sub
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Showing the value is a normal behavior for a range variable during debugging as it is the default property. You can see this when you reference `Target.address`.

Comment: Is it maybe not "time mismatch" but rather "type mismatch"? As per my answer below `Intersect` returns a range not a boolean. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following ammended code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim lastEntry As Integer
Dim shiftEntries As Range

lastEntry = LastEntryRow()
Set shiftEntries = Range("A11:L" & lastEntry)

If Not Intersect(Target, shiftEntries) Is Empty Then
    Dim shiftDate As String
    shiftDate = Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value
    Cells(10, 15) = ShiftsInSevenDays(shiftDate)
End If
End Sub
```

Intersect will return a range not a boolean (TRUE or FALSE). I am unsure if you should use `Is Empty` or `Is Nothing`, but it's one of the two. Regards,

Comment: Thanks nbayly. As a follow up question, if cells on multiple rows are selected, what is the best way to recognise this and get each selected row that intersects with shiftEntries seperately?

Comment: You can check how many rows selected from the property : `Selection.Rows.Count`. Then you can loop through your `Selection.Rows`  collection to check each rows intersection. Cheers